# how to htaccess mod rewrite php to mp4?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make htaccess changes for a project I'm working on. Although I don't know much about this subject, I would like to state that I have made a few experiments.

> thats a original link:
>
> www.example.com/media/14352/100/100/title-abc.php
>
> rewrite rule link:
>
> www.example.com/title-abc.mp4
>
> dynamic titles.
>
> or
>
> www.example.com/media/**14352/100/100**/title-abc.php
>
> www.example.com/media/**14352/100/100**/title-abc.mp4
>
> bold are dynamics

```
RewriteRule ^media/([0-9]+).mp4+$ (*).php [NC,QSA]
and
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).mp4+$ $1.php [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand this: If a user visits `www.example.com/title-abc.mp4`, you want to open the file `www.example.com/media/14352/100/100/title-abc.php`?

Comment: @Azer yes thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that implements what you ask is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.mp4$ /media/14352/100/100/$1.php [END]
```

I do not know if that really solves the idea you have... Thos folder hierarchies you apparently use in the server side file system are hard coded into above rule. There is no way to somehow magically guess them from the incoming request. So if that is a static path you use all is fine. However if you need different paths in the target, depending on the actual request, then you need to look for another strategy. I would suggest a routing script in that case which offers much more options.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

UPDATE:

Here is a variant of the above rule which relies on the path being part of the requested URL, so which only "changes" the "file name extension" in the URL (why do you need such an extension *at all* ?)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?media/(.+)\.mp4$ /media/$1.php [END]
```

Comment: i have godaddy standart wordpress hosting. but this rule not working. yes maybe that's hard, but alternatively I can just try changing the extension
ex;


www.example.com/media/14352/100/100/title-abc.php

www.example.com/media/14352/100/100/title-abc.mp4

Comment: What do you actually mean by "not working"? Certainly that rule does work. I assume you mean that it does not solve your idea, since it cannot magically guess the folder hierarchy? Or do you mean that the requests fail due to an error?  I added an update to the answer with an altered version of the rule implementing what you now suggested in your comment...

Comment: I still do not understand why you need a "file name extension", even considering your strange header redirection idea... But anyway, as already said: those rules _do_ work as such. Question is why they fail in your specific situation. Did you read what I wrote about the `END` flag? Have you checked that? Did you check your http server's error log file to find out what actually happens?

Comment: htaccass file have a  `RewriteRule . /index.php [L] ` rule i delete this rule working your rule. but 404 all wordpress pages. i need a multiple rule :/

Comment: Rules inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") are processed from top to bottom, so the order of the rules is important. Take care to place more specific rules at the top, more general rules at the bottom. So here you need to implement the media rewriting rules _before_ (so further up than) the general index rule.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Have fun!